# Can I use a deep fryer instead of a pot with oil?

Tags: deep-frying

I got a deep fryer for Christmas, and that made me think of all the donut recipes I have seen floating about, like [this one for crullers](http://notsohumblepie.blogspot.com/2011/04/french-crullers-with-honey-sugar-glaze.html) or [this one for chocolate dipped donuts](http://www.joythebaker.com/blog/2011/09/old-fashioned-doughnuts-with-chocolate-glaze/).

These are just two examples, but I noticed they all call for a pot filled with about 2 inches of oil heated to a certain temperature. My deep fryer does have adjustable temperature settings, so that would be fine, but I am not sure if using the deep fryer instead of the pot of oil would work.

Is a deep fryer an okay substitute? I really want to get some good use out of it, and this sounded somewhat plausible. Am I completely off-track?

Comment: Isn't a pot with oil a substitute for a deep fryer?

Comment: @Mien I suppose it could be. I have no idea - I am new to this whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely cook donuts in a deep fryer.  Most, if not all, donuts shops cook them in that manner.  Just make sure your temperature is good and use something like chopsticks to flip them.

Comment: I suspect that the recipes asking for as much as 2" of oil are written based on the assumption that the reader doesn't *have* a deep fryer... otherwise they'd just say to use the fryer.